# How do I create a makefile with only a main file and template header (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, makefile, header, template-classes

I'm trying to create a makefile that will compile two files:
-main.cpp
-queue.h
Inside of the header file I have the a full implementation of a template Queue class. The main file includes the header file.

I can test this code in the terminal (on a Mac) by typing this in:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o queue main.o
```

and I'm able to run the program (./queue) with no problem.

Now for this project it needs to compile by just typing "make" in the terminal.
For previous projects I used something like this:

```
all: sDeque

sDeque: sDeque.o sDeque_main.o
    g++ -o sDeque sDeque.o sDeque_main.o

sDeque.o: sDeque.cpp sDeque.h
    g++ -c sDeque.cpp

sDeque_main.o: sDeque_main.cpp sDeque.h
    g++ -c sDeque_main.cpp
clean:
    rm sDeque sDeque.o sDeque_main.o
```

But the example above has a main.cpp , sDeque.cpp and sDeque.h. And this works since I can create object files but I don't think I can create an object file from just a header file.

For the task at hand I only have the main and the header file (since its a template class).
How do I make the makefile for this?

Comment: Why are you writing your own Makefiles? Why not use something like cmake or qmake that generates Makefiles for a plethora of different platforms?

Comment: I need to include the makefile for the project, the professor is going to use his own main to test my template class and need to have a generic makefile for him.

Comment: You could still use cmake/qmake to generate the Makefile to ship off with your project. It's a lot easier to write and manage cmake/qmake files when your project grows, anyhow.

Comment: Actually, you _can_ create an object file from a header file, if there's a valid implementation in the file, but it's generally not good practice to put implementation in a header. That being said, if the prof is going to use his own main.cpp and you have a header you're providing, you can simply make a series of targets to make "main", consisting of the header, main.o and main.cpp files that he should be able to use, simply by extending your example in the post.

Comment: and how exactly do I use cmake/qmake? I'm new to the world of makefiles lol

Comment: @GusGus I actually disagree with Kenny. If you're just starting out, then you should understand the basics of make. I would suggest heading over to http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html and reading the end of chapter 3 of volume 1. Its a nice introduction and you can download for free.

Comment: Thank you Freddy! I will certainly take a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# All the targets
all: queue

# Dependencies and rule to make queue
queue: main.o
    g++ -o queue main.o

# Dependencies and rule to make main.o
main.o: main.cpp queue.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm queue main.o
```

Comment: This works perfectly! thank you so much. I wish i could upvote but I'm not of enough rep yet I guess?

Comment: @GusGus, no worries. When you have time, you should get to know [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). It has a lot of tricks up its sleeve.

Answer (score 0):

R Sahu's answer is correct, but note that you can do a lot better (less typing) by taking advantage of GNU make's built-in rules, which already know how to do this stuff.

In particular, if you rename your `main.cpp` file to `queue.cpp` (so that it has the same prefix as the program you want to generate, `queue`), your entire makefile can consist of just:

```
CXX = g++

all: queue
queue.o: queue.h

clean:
        rm queue queue.o
```

Comment: Except on Windows under MSYS, where implicit rules take _forever_ and you're best off (a) disabling them with `-r` and (b) writing the rules you need yourself, as in the other answer.

Comment: Even on Windows this simple makefile will not be annoyingly slow.  If it got significantly more complex then yes, you may need to do something about unneeded built-in rules.